# Specify cleanup by file age - PostgreSQL 9.2

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, archive, write-ahead-logging

I want to keep my `wal_files` for 30 days, using the pg_archivecleanup.

**I've followed these scripts:**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31346606/postgresql-automatic-archive-purge-not-occuring

and

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943599/how-to-specify-cleanup-by-file-age-or-date-with-pg-archivecleanup ...

```
#!/bin/bash

ARCHIVEDIR='/var/lib/pgsql/wal_archive'
CHECKPOINT=$(find $ARCHIVEDIR -type f -mtime +30 -type f -printf '%f\n' | sort -r | head -1)
cd $ARCHIVEDIR
/usr/bin/pg_archivecleanup $ARCHIVEDIR $CHECKPOINT

find $ARCHIVEDIR -type f -mtime +30 -a -type f -a ! -newer $CHECKPOINT -delete
```

... but it's not working for me.

I'm getting this error:

```
pg_archivecleanup: invalid filename input
Try "pg_archivecleanup --help" for more information.
find: `-delete': No such file or directory
```

**my recovery.conf:**

```
archive_cleanup_command = 'pg_archivecleaup_mv.bash -d'
```

Is there any way to make this work?

**UPDATE 1**:

I've done some tests...

recovery.conf:

```
archive_cleanup_command = 'pg_archivecleaup_mv.bash'
```

pg_archivecleaup_mv.bash:

```
declare -r -x PATH='/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin';

ARCHIVEDIR='/var/lib/pgsql/wal_archive'
CHECKPOINT=$(find $ARCHIVEDIR -type f -mmin +3 -type f -printf '%f\n' | sort -r | head -1)
cd $ARCHIVEDIR
exec "pg_archivecleanup" "$ARCHIVEDIR" "$CHECKPOINT" "%r";
find $ARCHIVEDIR -type f -mmin +3 -a -type f -a ! -newer $CHECKPOINT -delete
```

`-mmin +3` for testing purpose...

By doing that, the error changes:

```
pg_archivecleanup: too many parameters
Try "pg_archivecleanup --help" for more information.
archive_cleanup_command "/var/lib/pgsql/bin/pg_archivecleaup_mv.bash": return code 512
```

**UPDATE 2**: Following @Sebastian Webber idea, I changed the `pg_archivecleaup_mv.bash` script; I'm getting the same issue that I had using the script I wrote:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

ARCHIVEDIR='/var/lib/pgsql/wal_archive'
LAST_BACKUP=$(ls -lto ${ARCHIVEDIR})

FILE_LIST=$(/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin/pg_archivecleanup -n "${ARCHIVEDIR}" "${LAST_BACKUP}")

## TEST FIRST
/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin/pg_archivecleanup -n "${ARCHIVEDIR}" "${LAST_BACKUP}" | find -type f -mmin +30 | xargs ls -lh

##THEN UNCOMMENT THIS LINE
#/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin/pg_archivecleanup -n "${ARCHIVEDIR}" "${LAST_BACKUP}" | find -type f -mmin +30 -delete
```

**recovery.conf:**

```
archive_cleanup_command = 'exec /var/lib/pgsql/bin/pg_archivecleaup_mv.bash -d "%r"'
```

- With or without the `"%r"` I get the error: `pg_archivecleanup: invalid filename input`
- Without the `"%r"`, I put the %r into the script: `/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin/pg_archivecleanup -n "${ARCHIVEDIR}" "${LAST_BACKUP}" "%r"| find -type f -mmin +30 | xargs ls -lh` - Then I get the error: `pg_archivecleanup: too many parameters`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been solved.

**recovery.conf:**

```
archive_cleanup_command = 'exec /var/lib/pgsql/bin/pg_archivecleaup_mv.bash'
```

**Final pg_archivecleanup script:**

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -r -x PATH='/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin';

ARCHIVEDIR='/var/lib/pgsql/9.2/wal_archive'
LAST_BACKUP=$(ls -lto ${ARCHIVEDIR})

cd $ARCHIVEDIR
exec "/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin/pg_archivecleanup" -d /var/lib/pgsql/9.2/wal_archive ${LAST_BACKUP} | find $ARCHIVEDIR -type f -mmin +30 -delete
```

The scripts works fine. However, I'm getting an error:
`/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin/pg_archivecleanup: invalid option -- 'r'`

Anyway, I'll try to find that issue and then I edit this answer. But it's working.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you need to retain the archived `WAL` files it's a good pratice to put in another directory. If you use the archive files to recovery a standby server, i may prefer make a separated copy for it.

You can adjust that in your master server with the parameter `archive_command`.

Now, if you want to keep just one directory for same purpose, remember that 
`pg_archivecleanup` needs the archived wal location (seems ok with the variable `$ARCHIVEDIR`) and the last backup file (witch contains the first and last archived wal file for the backup, it contains a .backup extension, eg: `000000010000003700000010.00000020.backup`) and that it's missing.

To solve your script, find the latest `.backup` file on the `$ARCHIVEDIR` directory and call `pg_archivecleanup` with the `-n` option to get a list of wal files to delete then use that list to find the files older than 30 days.

My idea it's something like this:

https://gist.github.com/sebastianwebber/855585ef3ef6a50c50cca7b57bc8d7d3#file-pg_cleanup_oldmorethan_30days-sh

Please, take a look at the documentation for more details:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgarchivecleanup.html

Comment: Thank @Sebastian. Please, would be nice if you could give me an example.. I wasn't using `pg_basebackup` to do this... do I need to? Cheers

Comment: I just update with a gist sample. please **test before remove the files**.

Comment: Oh ok! You wrote `pg_basebackup` but I think you meant `pg_archivecleanup` - I'm testing your script... I got an error: `pg_archivecleanup: invalid filename input` but will try to solve it. Also, I noticed that I get a list of all the data inside /var/lib/pgsql/9.2/data - It's like if I do: `ls -la` in that directory... do you know why?

Comment: yes @PatrickB. I mean `pg_archivecleanup`. I update the response. :)

Comment: run the script again with `bash -x` to see this inputs and the error properly.

Comment: `pg_archivecleanup: too many parameters` - That's what I got... any ideas? Can't figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing this with pg_archivecleanup at all?  The point of pg_archivecleanup is that it selects which files to remove based on the needs of the standby.  But that apparently isn't what you want to do.

If you want to delete files older than 30 days, just write a `find` command that deletes files older than 30 days, and invoke it once a day from `cron` or your favorite scheduler.

```
find $ARCHIVEDIR -type f -mtime +30 -delete
```

Comment: I'm wanna keep the wal_files for 30 days or longer. Postgres does not do that. I need a bash script, that's what I'm trying to write. But I'm getting erros as you can see above. I'm already using the command you provided. Just the `FIND` does not solve my problem. I need that pg_archivecleanup does that job.

Comment: So, what does my example do that you don't want done, or not do that you do want done?  We can't reverse engineer what you want out of your examples, because your examples don't do what you want.

Comment: the `find` command you provided will just delete the files older than X days... but first, I need to keep the files... I have to keep the files for 30 days and then delete the older ones.